# webapp2 DomainRoute is not matching

Tags: python, subdomain, webapp2

I'm trying to launch a webserver serving several sites under several subdomains.
I'm using Pythen with webapp2 and paste. My Server is behind a router that asigns a static IP adress to the server and forwards port 80. The router itself has no static IP adress assigned by my ISP so I'm using DDNS (lets say example.dlinkddns.com) .
In my folder hierarchy each folder represents a subdomain and is a python module.

Like this:

```
server/app.py
server/www
  server/www/__init__.py
server/test
  server/test/__init__.py
```

they should be reachable via www.mydomain.com and test.mydomain.com
I set *.mydomain.com to be a CNAME for example.dlinkddns.com

This is server/app.py:

```python
import sys
import os

import webapp2
from webapp2_extras import routes

from paste import httpserver

DOMAIN = 'mydomain.com'

class Fallback(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args, **kw):
        self.response.write('Fallback...\n'+str(args)+'\n'+str(kw))

def main():
    dirs = [name for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]
    dirs.remove('env') # folder created by package virtualenv - needed for paste

    rs = []
    for subdomain in dirs:
        # import subdomain package
        exec('import '+subdomain)
        # add routes defined for subdomain
        exec('rs += [routes.DomainRoute("'+subdomain+'.'+DOMAIN+'", '+subdomain+'.routes)]')
    rs += [routes.DomainRoute("<domain:.*>",[webapp2.Route('/<:.*>',Fallback,name='fallback')])]

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(rs)   

    httpserver.serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port='80')  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is how my www package looks like:

```python
__init__.py
import webapp2

class MainMain(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,target):
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2! www.mydomain.com at:'+target)

routes = [
    webapp2.Route('/<target>', handler=MainMain, name='main-main')
]
```

The problem now is, when I visit www.mydomain.com the fallback handler seems to match but MainMain handler should.
The output is

```
Fallback... () {'domain':'0.0.0.0'}.
```

It looks like my app wouldn't recognize the domains at all. Same thing happens when I visit example.dlinkddns.com.
I also tried it without the fallback handler but then it only showed me the 404 page for every route and every domain...

I also tried to start the server with

```
httpserver.serve(app, host='192.168.178.33', port='80')
```

This is the static assigned IP address of my server in my LAN. The the output changes to

```
Fallback... () {'domain':'192.168.178.33'}.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can nobody help me? I'm so desperate. I tried so much but nothing would help -.-

Comment: I found a line in webapp2_extras that could be buggy... I'll give that a try as soon as I have time for it.